# bepbmhgboaologfdajaanbcjmnhjmhfn.crx suspicious file in chrome (MAC)

Tags: google-chrome, virus, chrome-extensions

When I open this chrome this file downloads automatically. I don't know what is it. But I think this is some malicious file. How fix it? An other get around it, other than just quickly resetting everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about the fancy name?

But .crx is Chrome Extension type.

So check for Chrome extensions you have installed.

According to Google Chromium it is a part of the Google Voice:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357738

Comment: What to check? There's no extension with this name

Comment: I mean for you to check what Extensions you have installed, and maybe disable them to check the problem.

Comment: i did that earlier but didn't fixed my problem

Comment: It looks like it is a part of Google Voice. It is a Google Voice Search Hotword Id:  bepbmhgboaologfdajaanbcjmnhjmhfn.

Comment: So its safe then?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it and if its a google thing than i don't think its malicious...thanks for telling